# Error with JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have a problem with JPA and JPQL. I have the next query:

```
String query="SELECT c from Cliente c";
Query quer=em.createQuery("Select c from Cliente c");
List<Cliente> lista= quer.getResultList();
```

When I execute that, i hace the following error :

> [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException
>        [java]     at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.java:59)
>        [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:103)
>        [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
>        [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
>        [java]     at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
>        [java]     at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
>        [java]     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1735)
>        [java]     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
>        [java]     at test.TestCliente.main(TestCliente.java:35)
>        [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.RecognitionException
>        [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>        [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>        [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>        [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>        [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>        [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>        [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>        [java]     ... 9 more

The class CLiente is accesible, but I cant make a query.

Anyone knows why?

EDIT: In the classpath is the class RecognitionException and I can import him, so i dont know what is the problem.

Comment: It seems that you have a classpath problem. Make sure the version of antlr that Hibernate depends on is in the classpath.

Comment: How did you add hibernate to your project? You should know that. Check that you have an antlr jar file listed, and that its version is the one expected by Hibernate.

Comment: I add the antlr lib to the classpath but it not works.

Comment: what version of hibernate and what version of antlr jar do you have?

Comment: antlr v4 and hibernate-core-4.1.8, hibernate-entitymanger 4.1.8 and hibernate annotations 4.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely have the wrong antlr jar. I just looked it up in one of my maven projects that uses hibernate.

I have hibernate-core-4.1.8 and antlr-2.7.7, it works there.

You can always lookup the correct version in the pom.xml of hibernate-core of your specific version.

Be sure to fix the two places for the correct version number
e.G. for 4.1.8:

```
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.8.Final/hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.pom
                                                           ^ ^ ^                      ^ ^ ^
```

or browse to the version overview: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/ and select your version, then 'pom.xml'. Look in the `dependencies` section for the `antlr` entry and there you go.

Comment: Thanks! it fail for the version. I donwload that antlr jar and it works. Thanks you very much.

Comment: I using hibernate 5.0.11 and antlr 3.5.2 but does not works.

Comment: @e-info128 You need 2.7.7 Look at the pom of hibernate-core. There you have the dependency structure. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.11.Final/hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.pom

Comment: @e-info128 I added information on how to obtain the correct version information in my answer. Please review.

Comment: My solution: delete marven folder (~/.m2/) and download all again, the library antlr are corrupt.

Comment: @e-info128 If something like this happens to you again: You only need to delete the repository part with the corrupted jars in it. I sometimes have that as well when my proxy setup fails somehow.